# How to include project dependency PDBs in local debug of Azure Functions?

Tags: azure-functions

I have an Azure Function that I'm debugging locally in Visual Studio 2019 and am unable to load the debug symbols from another project in the same solution that is referenced in this project. Viewing the debug modules window, I can see that the PDB symbol file is not loading for the dependent project. The PDB file is generated in the debug directory however.

I've added the symbol file location in symbol settings, un-checked the "just my code" option, and set debugging information to "full". "Load all modules" is selected, and there are no excluded modules specified. The project is appearing under "dependencies" > "projects" in the solution explorer. "Debug" configuration is set as well.

Is there something else I can do to force a load of the dependent project PDB file? Or, is there a reason why I can't debug a dependent project with an Azure Function?

Comment: In Configuration Manager, are all of the projects set to Debug mode for the Debug configuration?

Comment: @Brian, yes, all of the projects are set to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Functions will show dependency project symbols as not loaded when debugging until something in that dependency is hit while running. Once it is hit, it will appear in the Debug > Windows > Modules list and the breakpoints will switch from the red circle outline to the solid red circle indicating the breakpoint will be hit and the symbols have been loaded.